# Use jQuery display a text in a limited label

Tags: jquery, html, css, label

I have a label and it's length is limited. I want to do this: when the text's length is longer than the label, the end words of text will instead of "..."

How can do this with jQuery or JavaScript?

I have no idea of this, any advise?

Comment: Here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without JS.

```
label{
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372399/use-jquery-display-a-text-in-a-limited-label/20372440#20372440)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with pure CSS. For instance, use `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

You will get what you are looking for.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FGCmf/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 50px; 
  width: 120px; height: 50px; border: thin solid black;
  overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis">
  <nobr>This is a NOBR section</nobr>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div { position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 50px; width: 120px; height: 50px; border: thin solid black; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
```

Hope this helps.