# Adding ellipsis using "dotdotdot" jquery plugin for dropdowns

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, callback, ellipsis

I am trying to use the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) jQuery plugin. It works fine in most of the cases. But in dropdowns, it doesn't work as I expected . I found out that it is because my dropdowns are `display:hidden;` is preventing the plugin to function normally. Though I can add `watch:true;` to make it work,

> $(".wrapper").dotdotdot({ 
>           watch:
>   true});

the problem is, the toggle event is called before the dotdotdot function, it makes the user can see the original content for 0.1 second before it get truncated, which is not what I want. I am not sure how to make it perform normally cause even if I use callbacks, there are problems, as when the toggle event is called first, then there is the problem mentioned above. If dotdotdot is called first, it simply doesn't work as initially the div is `display:none;`. Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372399/use-jquery-display-a-text-in-a-limited-label/20372440#20372440

Comment: The problem of the CSS solution is that it only works for single lines, but not paragraphs

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/newpen/jRRUH/](http://jsfiddle.net/newpen/jRRUH/)
Mine is worse though. Dunno what's the difference

Comment: well somehow it's fine now. See the demo above if you are interested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Problem solved](http://jsfiddle.net/newpen/jRRUH/). Thank you for your attention.

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
 $('.dd').toggle();    
 $('.dd').dotdotdot({
        //  configuration goes here
  });
});
```